# Calling VB.net button click event from javascript confirm box

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to call a vb.net button on click event from java script confirm box when the user clicks ok.

```
                    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
                    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
                    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
                    sb.Append("if (confirm('")
                    sb.Append(message)

                    sb.Append("')){ ") //btn Click event


                    sb.Append("}")
                    sb.Append("else{")
                    sb.Append("window.location = 'SA.aspx?PID=" & Request("PID") & "';")
                    sb.Append("}};</script>")
                    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "confirm", sb.ToString())
```

Comment: Well, [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is typically a good starting point for doing something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Where ctl is the name of the vb.net control

Using jQuery
   $('<%= ctl.ClientID %>').click();

or

Or regular Javascript
    document.getElementById('<%= ctl.ClientID %>').click();

Comment: Could you please tell how to integrate this particular line in the exisiting code.

Comment: Goes after line //btn click event  
        sb.Append("document.getElementById('{0}').click();", btn.ClientID);

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
sb.AppendFormat("__doPostBack('{0}','');", yourButton.ClientID);
```

This will cause the click handler to be called on the server. If you don't have any handler for the button the answer is simpler: you just need to submit the form.